# Npm - Unexpected token } in JSON at position 0

Tags: json, node.js, npm

Yesterday I installed the JSDoc package using `npm install -g jsdoc` and used it just fine. Today when I tried to use it again, I got the following error:

```
module.js:96
    throw e;
    ^

SyntaxError: Error parsing ...npm\node_modules\jsdoc\node_modules\requizzle\package.json: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 0
    at Object.parse (native)
    at readPackage (module.js:92:52)
    at tryPackage (module.js:102:13)
    at Function.Module._findPath (module.js:172:20)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:438:25)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:388:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

I've actually gotten this numerous times before and a clean reinstall of the package fixes it, but I was wondering what keeps causing this error and if a more permanent fix were available.

When I open up the `package.json` file mentioned in the error, it looks like a binary file with a bunch of weird symbols.

[image]

I see that the first character is a `}` which kinda explains the error. Thing is all the package.json files for every package I download looks like that, and it works the first time so npm apparently can parse this.

**EDIT:**

Quick note: I am on my office laptop.

Ok so I cleaned out the `node_modules` folder and reinstalled jsdoc with `npm install -g jsdoc`. I checked the `package.json` file: it's all plaintext and looks great.

I then shut down and start up my computer. Not only is the jsdoc `package.json` file obfuscated, *the `package.json` files of all its dependencies are also obfuscated!* This little bug is recursive!

To test it further, I took the json file, duplicated it and renamed it `PACKAGE_DUP.json` and placed it right next to the original json file. I also took the `node_modules` folder and made a copy called `NODE_MOD_DUP`, again next to the original. So now there are 4 `package.json` files:

1. `node_modules/package.json`
2. `node_modules/PACKAGE_DUP.json`
3. `NODE_MOD_DUP/package.json`
4. `NODE_MOD_DUP/PACKAGE_DUP.json`

When I restarted my computer, the *only* json file affected was the `package.json` file in the `node_modules` folder (item number 1). So it's being targeted by something!

Virus scans are coming up clean, and every other json file in the modules folders and on my system as a whole are completely unscathed. Also, the `package.json` files that come with the modules bundled with node work fine. It's only modules installed with `npm install` that are giving me a problem (whether installed globally or locally for that matter).

Comment: `package.json` should be a proper JSON file, not something binary. Are you sure that your machine isn't infected by mal-/ransomware?

Comment: This is my work laptop. It has a proxy but I configured it (or at least I think so. Earlier I couldn't even download anything, but after configuration I could, so it _should_ be alright?)

Comment: I wouldn't expect npm to be able to parse that. Take a look at `package.json` immediately after you reinstall the package. *Something* is replacing it with that binary garbage. One suggestion: Check the timestamp of the file after it's corrupted, and try to figure out just what you were doing at that time. Check for malware.

Comment: I have no idea, but if files that worked yesterday suddenly stop working today, _and_ are obviously overwritten by _seemingly_ random data, I'd start to worry.

Comment: According to the properties dialog, the file in question was created and modified at ‎`Yesterday, ‎June ‎06, ‎2016, ‏‎5:32:51 PM`. But I re-downloaded the package, and it's a normal json file now... weird. Like I said, this is a work laptop, it might be doing something weird to my files...

Comment: @KeithThompson I updated the question with my new findings

Comment: Try this on a different computer and since this could be a case of seriously bad malware, keep that computer off until you can rule out that possibility. Connecting to any network drives can scramble their contents permanently.

Comment: @tadman Right now it doesn't seem to be any malicious software doing this (virus scan was clean) and is most likely a bug or perhaps even an encoding issue of some kind. However, you are right that this could affect everyone else's stuff potentially, so is there a way I can pinpoint what's causing this?

Comment: Having files randomly mangled on your computer is never a good thing. Try grabbing and reinstalling NPM from scratch if you can.

Comment: @rcplusplus Were you able to resolve this issue? I am also facing the same for my work laptop.

Comment: @VikasArora lol yes in the sense I wrote a quick and dirty shell script that cleared the packages folder and redownloaded them. Not really a fix, but it worked, and I left it at my workplace and instructions on how to use it.

Comment: Thanks @rcplusplus, I will also do the same for time being.